# gestureEnable is not working react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

here's my code. On 'NewUserVerify' just load the 'NewProfile', and on this screen keeps allowing swipe back. What i'm doing wrong?

```
const VerifyNewUserStackScreen = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="NewUserVerify"
    screenOptions={{
      gestureEnabled: false,
      swipeEnabled: false
    }}
  >    
    
    <Stack.Screen name="NewUserVerify" 
      component={VerifyNewUser}    
    />  

    <Stack.Screen name="NewProfile" 
      component={NewProfile} 
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: false
      }}      
      screenOptions={{
        gestureEnabled: false,
        swipeEnabled: false
      }}
    />

    <Stack.Screen name="Home" 
      component={TabStackScreen} 
    />

  </Stack.Navigator> 
)
```

Comment: When you navigate to NewProfile, reset the index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, makes sense do that. I tried that but now give a error, i read about it and didn't find anything // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/stack-actions/#reset -> give me a error 'The action 'Navigation/RESET' was not handled by any navigator.' // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/navigation-actions/#reset-> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near'..._reactNavigation.NavigationActions.reset

Comment: i copy the link because my code inside the if/else that redirect to NewProfile or Home is exactly the same of the example, changing just the routeName

Comment: You're using navigation version 5 but reading a docs for version 3?

Comment: I'm embarrassed that i didn't notice it. But i using the new version now reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace and keeps allowing swipe

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To reset the index, you can do something like this

```
this.props.navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [
    {
      name: "NewProfile"
    }
  ]
});
```